# How to get a unix timestamp for specific hour?

Tags: ios, swift, date

How can you get a unix timestamp for a specific timepoint? For example how would I convert current day 16:30 ET time to a timestamp ?

Comment: Create a Date object and use the property `timeIntervalSince1970`

Comment: Do you mean 4:30pm of the user's current timezone ?

Comment: @LeoDabus  I mean 4:30pm of ET timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use calendar method `date(bySettingHour:)` and set the desired time.

```
let now = Date()
if let currentTimezoneTimeStamp = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 16, minute: 30, second: 0, of: now)?.timeIntervalSince1970 {
    currentTimezoneTimeStamp  // 1606246200  "GMT-3"
}
```

---

If you need to specify a specific timezone you can set the calendar's timezone property:

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/New_York")!
if let newYorkTimeStamp = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 16, minute: 30, second: 0, of: now)?.timeIntervalSince1970 {
    newYorkTimeStamp          // 1606253400  "GMT-5"
}
```